# Is "meeting you here" the appositive of "a coincidence"?

Tags: gerunds, appositives

> What a coincidence meeting you here!

Today, I came across this expression for the first time.
I have three questions of this sentence.

1. Is "meeting you here" the appositive of "a coincidence"?
2. If 1 is correct, must a comma be there between coincidence and meeting as in "What a coincidence, meeting you here!"?
3. I think "meeting you here" must be connected to the coincidence by the preposition, of, if we want to get rid of the comma, as in "What a coincidence of meeting you here!".

Please check whether my thinking is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence:

> What a coincidence meeting you here!

"meeting you here" is not an appositive at all. An appositive is always a noun or noun phrase. It redefines, clarifies, or gives information about its referent (often called its antecedent, although an appositive can come before the referent). It is often either a non-defining, parenthetical clause, or else a restrictive, defining clause. A series of nouns used as adjectives to form a noun phrase can also be called appositives, as in "fallout survival shelter".

Instead "meeting you here" is the object. This is celarer when the elided words in the sentence are restored:

> What a coincidence [it is,] meeting you here!

This helps one to see that "meeting you here" is the thing that is a coincidence, andx the object of [implied] "is". Without the implied "is" the original sentence has no verb.

Comment: Maybe, is "to be" implied between coincidence and meeting, as in "What a coincidence (to be) meeting you here!"?